# What's the difference between Homebrew formula `texlive` and cask `mactex`?

Tags: mactex, macos, homebrew

I've always used mactex but just realized that Homebrew has a formula called `texlive`. What's the difference?

Is `texlive` everything `mactex` contains except MacTeXtras, which includes "Additional Front Ends, Spell Checkers, Documentation, and Showcase items" (https://www.tug.org/mactex/aboutmactex.html)?

Comment: The vanilla version of mactex is texlive+some tools, like a gui to switch between different texlive versions, an editor etc. It is up to you if you want these tools or not. However beware of the homebrew version of texlive. If I remember correctly, it disables some update mechanism of texlive and I think there where some problems with path?. I would install a vanilla texlive instead of a homebrew texlive. I'm not sure if I remember correctly, but I think installing mactex through homebrew should be more or less the same as installing vanilla mactex because it is a cask?

Comment: ... So decide if you want texlive or mactex and if you decide on texlive, don't install it via homebrew. You can find installation instructions at https://tug.org/texlive/

Comment: ... see this discussion https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4226#discussioncomment-5008376 about the problems with tlmgr for the homebrew version of texlive.